# Renaming folders and files while os.walk()ing them missed some files after change of the directory name

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a folder structure like this:

```
Template
  - Template1
  - Template2
TemplateTest
  - TemplateTest1
Config
  - TemplateConfig
```

I want to replace 'Template' with 'MyApp' for every single file name and every single folder name.

This is my code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith("Template"):
            replace = name.replace("Template",'MyApp')
            os.rename(os.path.join(root,name),os.path.join(root,name.replace(old,new)))
    for name in dirs:
        if name.startswith("Template"):
            replace = name.replace("Template",'MyApp')
            os.rename(os.path.join(root,name),os.path.join(root,replace))
```

The odd thing is, this only replaces the folder name and the file name who's parent folder name doesn't require change. Like this:

```
MyApp
  - Template1
  - Template2
MyAppTest
  - TemplateTest1
Config
  - MyAppConfig
```

but if I execute this code twice then it will replace the files. 
I am wondering why and how do I change the code so it's replacing everything I need?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Hand typed folder names, sorry, they are meant to be the same.

Comment: Can you try by first renaming only the directories and then renaming the files using `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):` TWICE

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes I already found out that I need to execute this twice to get what I want. I am curious why and is there any way I can just change it all at once.

Comment: what are `old` and `new` ? not given.

Comment: What platform are you using? This worked fine for me on windows 10... after I replace `old,new` line with `os.rename(os.path.join(root,name),os.path.join(root,replace))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note that the call signature for `os.walk` is:

```
os.walk = walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
```

so you're passing `True`, `None`, and `False`.)

The problem has to do with the order in which `os.walk` walks the directories and files, and which directories and files it walks into.

In particular, it starts by reading the directory at `path`.  This produces the following:

```
['Template', 'TemplateTest', 'Config']
```

All of these are directories so the list of subdirectories it will walk next time is the same, and there are no files.  This gets returned as the three values in the first iteration:

```
path
['Template', 'TemplateTest', 'Config']
[]
```

You then do your own code, in which you call `os.rename` on `Template`, so that it's now named `MyApp`, and on `TemplateTest`, so that the directory is now named `MyAppTest`.

Next, the `os.walk` code tries to read subdirectory `Template`.  This fails, so nothing happens (`onerror` is `None`).

Next, the `os.walk` code tries to read subdirectory `TemplateTest`.  This fails, so nothing happens.

Finally, the `os.walk` code tries to read subdirectory `Config`.  This succeeds and all goes well.

There are two different solutions: you can set `topdown` to `False`, or you can update the list named `dirs` so that `os.walk` knows the *new* names of the directories.  (Edit: I'm not sure `topdown=False` will fix it; that would require testing.)

(Edit: `topdown=False` realy will fix it. This is described in the documentation:

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes walk() again. Modifying dirnames when topdown is False has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up mode the directories in dirnames are generated before dirpath itself is generated.

)

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt - `print` it:

### Create data structure:

```
import os


for d in ["./Template","./TemplateTest","./Config"]:
    os.mkdir(d)

for f in ["./Template/Template1.txt","./Template/Template2.txt",
          "./TemplateTest/TemplateTest1.txt", "./Config/TemplateConfig.txt"]:
    with open(f,"w") as f:
        f.write(" ")
```

### Test `os.walk`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./"): # no topdown means == True
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith("Template"):
            replace = name.replace("Template",'MyApp')
            print("renaming: ", os.path.join(root,name), " to ", os.path.join(root,replace))
            # os.rename(os.path.join(root,name),os.path.join(root,replace))
    for name in dirs:
        if name.startswith("Template"):
            replace = name.replace("Template",'MyApp')
            print("renaming: ", os.path.join(root,name), " to ", os.path.join(root,replace))
            # os.rename(os.path.join(root,name),os.path.join(root,replace))
```

Output if you comment out the `for ... loops` and just `print(root,dirs,files)` you get:

```
./             ['Config', 'Template', 'TemplateTest'] ['main.py']
./Config       []                                     ['TemplateConfig.txt']
./Template     []                                     ['Template1.txt', 'Template2.txt']
./TemplateTest []                                     ['TemplateTest1.txt']
```

If you comment the for loops in again and replace rename with `print` you get:

```
renaming:  ./Template  to  ./MyApp            # aha - works
renaming:  ./TemplateTest  to  ./MyAppTest    # aha - works 
renaming:  ./Config/TemplateConfig.txt  to  ./Config/MyAppConfig.txt   # works
renaming:  ./Template/Template1.txt  to  ./Template/MyApp1.txt       # folder not updated
renaming:  ./Template/Template2.txt  to  ./Template/MyApp2.txt       # folder also not updated
renaming:  ./TemplateTest/TemplateTest1.txt  to  ./TemplateTest/MyAppTest1.txt  # also not updated
```

If you take a peek into the documentation it probably says that changes while iterating the generated results of os.walk() are not reflected in the generated data.

You essentially "change a interable while iterating it" ;o)

From the linked doku:

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.
>   Modifying dirnames when `topdown` is `False` has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up mode the directories in dirnames are generated before dirpath itself is generated.

Comment: :-D Thank you. I guess I'll just have to run it twice then.